# error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition

Tags: c++, templates, simd

I am trying to include a SIMD library into some other huge software library. And already after including the corresponding header `#include "xsimd/xsimd.hpp"` I get following errors:

[image]

The problem is, I don't even have a clue where to start to look for solutions, since those errors sound too general to me. I already tried to use the XSimd library in some small example and it compiled just fine (using the same XSimd version, the same compiler, as well as the same C++14 standard).

Do you have any suggestions on how to approach the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Create a [mre] to show us, then copy-paste it *as text* into your question. The same with the error from the shown example code, copy-paste it as text.

Comment: Add `-DNOMINMAX` when compiling since you are using MSVC.

Comment: You also need to use C++17 or later. I suggest using C++20, so add  `/std:c++20`  when compiling too.